# Keepalived can't bind to vip and no error report

Tags: configuration, keepalived

I need your help.My keepalived can't bind to vip,and i couldn't find any error.This is my log in /var/log/message.By the way,I use Centos6.5

```
[vagrant@director1 ~]$ sudo tail /var/log/messages 
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14272]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14272]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Netlink reflector reports IP 10.0.2.15 added
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Netlink reflector reports IP 192.168.1.104 added
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::a00:27ff:fec7:8f23 added
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::a00:27ff:fe55:b1cd added
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
May 26 09:35:53 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[14273]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
[vagrant@director1 ~]$ sudo tail /var/log/messages 
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15242]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived[24939]: VRRP child process(15242) died: Respawning
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived[24939]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=15243
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15243]: Netlink reflector reports IP 10.0.2.15 added
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15243]: Netlink reflector reports IP 192.168.1.104 added
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15243]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::a00:27ff:fec7:8f23 added
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15243]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::a00:27ff:fe55:b1cd added
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15243]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15243]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
May 26 09:35:57 director1 Keepalived_vrrp[15243]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
```

The worst thing is it always print that,and I don't know what's the matter going on.

Here is my keepalived.conf,it's at /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
! Configuration File for keepalived

global_defs {
    notification_email {
    willcream@126.com

  }
   notification_email_from Keepalived@localhost
   smtp_server 127.0.0.1
   smtp_connect_timeout 30
   router_id LVS_DEVEL
}

vrrp_sync_group G1{
    group{
        VI_1
    }
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    smtp_alert
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass baidu
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.1.99/24 dev eth1 label eth1:0
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Here is my "ip a" output.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c7:8f:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fec7:8f23/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:55:b1:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.104/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe55:b1cd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please share `ip a` output.

Comment: Ok,I update my question and you can see it at the end.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make lab and found that your config starting only when remove this section:

```
vrrp_sync_group G1{
    group{
        VI_1
    }
}
```

If you want to start `keepalived` that's enough, but it required additional investigation why it not starting.

Comment: Yeah,it works! And I think I should read the manual again,thank you so much.